# Please tell me where is the error here

Tags: .net

I want to filter my Dataview by Textbox control but when i run program it says the following error

" Cannot find Table 0"

Here is My code

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "\Kyc.mdb"
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmdfilter As String = " select ID as الرقم_الوطني,fname as الاسم_الاول,sname as الاسم_الثاني,thname as الاسم_الثالث,finame as الاسم_الرابع from O_name "
        Dim dataadabtar As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdfilter, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dsview As DataView
        Dim bs As New BindingSource
        dsview = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
        bs.DataSource = dsview
        bs.Filter = "الرقم_الوطني LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
        conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Please help me

Comment: The error is you're never filling `ds` with any data.

Comment: You instantiate an empty dataset and then immediately try to reference a table in that dataset.  Just as the error states, there is no table there.  So you can't reference it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from this part of your code..

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
....
dsview = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

You never assign ds

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Dim dataadabtar As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdfilter, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dsview As DataView
    Dim bs As New BindingSource

    dataadabtar.Fill(ds);

    IF ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
      dsview = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
      bs.DataSource = dsview
      bs.Filter = "الرقم_الوطني LIKE '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
      DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
    END IF;
```

Comment: this works and eliminate the error but no results shown when i write any number in textbox the datagrid become empty just and when i remove from textbox  it's stay empty

Comment: are you sure there is data for the numbers you are passing? This answer solves your original question above